# Saving displayed output from terminal to file with a nice format

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need to "dump" all information from different commands to a file in bash. When I enter the command at the terminal it shows with a pretty nice formatted and is readable. For example I have this command

```
ifconfig -a | grep  "inet\|lo\|eth\|wlan"
```

and I want that output in a file I do this

```
echo $(ifconfig -a | grep  "inet\|lo\|eth\|wlan") >> filename.txt
```

but when I open **filename.txt** everything is 
like this

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr # inet addr:#Bcast:# Mask:# inet6 addr: # Scope:Link eth0:1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr # inet addr:127.0.0.1 Bcast:127.255.255.255 Mask:255.0.0.0 lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

but I want it to look like the terminal output something like this

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet 
HWaddr # 
inet addr:# 
Bcast:#
Mask:# 
inet6 addr: #
Scope:Link 
eth0:1 Link encap:Ethernet 
HWaddr # 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 
Bcast:127.255.255.255 
Mask:255.0.0.0 lo Link 
encap:Local 
Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 
Mask:255.0.0.0 
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

is it possible? I've been trying to replace "space" with \n with a sed command
for example `sed "s/ /\n/#"` where # represent what space to remove, but this is clearly not the way to go. There must be another way to what I want. Its not only ifconfig command I need to have formatted.

Comment: Totally pointless `echo` and command substitution.

Comment: @4ae1e1 It's not totally pointless - the point of `echo $(...)` is to remove newlines... Of course, that's exactly what the OP is *not* wanting to do...

Comment: @twalberg I know what `echo` does and doesn't do, thank you. Also, `echo $(...)` does more than removing newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing can be done simply with:

```
ifconfig -a | grep  "inet\|lo\|eth\|wlan" >> filename.txt
```

or

```
grep  "inet\|lo\|eth\|wlan" <<<"$(ifconfig -a)" >> filename.txt
```

And the reason for the "different" output in your current code is because all the whitespaces are lost. If you do:

```
echo "$(ifconfig -a | grep  "inet\|lo\|eth\|wlan")" >> filename.txt
```

you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: It might worth pointing out that the `echo` version works because if you quote it you keep everything as a single argument, otherwise the output of the command is subject to [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) so each "word" becomes its own argument to `echo`

Comment: Omg Thanks! It was that simple